# How to vectorize a "for" loop that returns a vector after applying a function for each ID

Tags: r

I am interested in finding a way to vectorize (using ddply or some other apply function) the following:

```
day = seq(0,100,20)
d = data.frame(id=rep(seq(1:10),each=length(day)))
d$s = rnorm(nrow(d),0,1)
d$diffS = NA
for(i in unique(d$id)) {
  d$diffS[d$id==i] = c(0,diff(d$s[d$id==i]))
}
```

Essentially I am looking for a more clever way of taking a subset of a dataframe by ID, apply a function that returns a vector and add it back the the dataframe. I thought maybe the "by" function would work, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could also be achieved by the following

Using `ddply`

```
library('plyr')
out = ddply(d, .(id), mutate, diffs = c(0,diff(s)))
```

Or `tapply`

```
d$diffs = unlist(tapply(d$s, d$id, function(x) c(0, diff(x))))
```

Or `lapply`

```
out = do.call(rbind, 
      lapply(split(d, f = d$id), 
      function(x){x$diffs = c(0,diff(x$s)); x}))
```

Or `sapply`

```
library('reshape')
d$diffs = melt(sapply(split(d, d$id), function(x) c(0, diff(x$s))))$value
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try one of the `aggregating` functions

```
d$diffS <- with(d, ave(s, id, FUN=function(x) c(0, diff(x))))
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(diffS= c(0, diff(s)))
```

Or

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(d)[, diffS:= c(0, diff(s)), by = id]
```

As @Arun mentioned in the comments, the devel version of 'data.table' has `shift` which would be more efficient.  Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
setDT(d)[, diffS := s-shift(s, fill=0), by = id]
```

Comment: `diff(s)` creates a vector (mem allocation), and `c(0, .)` creates another entirely new vector (another mem allocation). Using `shift(s, fill=0)` would be efficient (but requires `v1.9.5+`).

Comment: @DavidS I would also prefer `dplyr` or `data.table` or  plyr's `ddply` over apply functions as they are more efficient and quick. @akrun as far as I know `tapply` do not mess with the order of the groups. do you have any example for this

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar It's okay.  I was a bit curious about the OP's decision.  That's all.  Regarding the `tapply` order.  for example, `set.seed(24);df1 <- data.frame(group= sample(LETTERS[1:4], 25, replace=TRUE), val=rnorm(25));res1 <- unlist(with(df1, tapply(val, group, FUN=function(x) c(0, diff(x)))), use.names=FALSE); res2 <- with(df1, ave(val, group, FUN=function(x) c(0, diff(x))))`  You can notice that the order of value is different.  So, if you do `d1$diffS <- res1`, it will be different

Answer (score 3):

Because you mentioned the function `by`:

```
using_by <- with(d, by(s, id, FUN=function(x) c(0, diff(x))))
```

It isn't recommended because of the output layout. It isn't conducive to attachment with a data frame,

```
id: 1
[1]  0.0000000  1.7884528  0.8135887  0.1891395 -0.6823383
[6] -2.6844915
--------------------------------------------- 
id: 2
[1]  0.0000000 -0.0258939 -0.8095359  0.5238898 -1.0345254
[6]  1.5432667
```

To fix it to the data, an extra step should be taken:

```
d$diffS <- unname(unlist(using_by))
```